# GLUT Fatal Error when using Haskell Graphics.Gloss

Tags: multithreading, haskell, graphics, thread-safety, glut

I am following **[this tutorial](http://andrew.gibiansky.com/blog/haskell/haskell-gloss/#_basic_drawing)** and have created a `demo.hs` file with the following:

```
import Graphics.Gloss

window :: Display
window = InWindow "Nice Window" (200, 200) (10, 10)

background :: Color
background = white

drawing :: Picture
drawing = circle 80

main :: IO ()
main = display window background drawing
```

However, when I execute `runhaskell demo.hs` in my terminal, I get the following error message:

```
GLUT Fatal Error: internal error: NSInternalInconsistencyException, reason: nextEventMatchingMask should only be called from the Main Thread!
```

What does this error mean, and how can I fix it? I am using macOS Sierra version 10.12.5.

Comment: Gui stuff has to be done in the main thread in MacOS. Look up `forkOS` to see how to run things on a specific OS thread. I don't have a Mac but there is probably some documentation online regarding running things on the main thread in Haskell

Comment: @DanRobertson there is no forking involved here.

Comment: @Turion indeed, `forkOS` does not use `fork(2)`

Comment: @DanRobertson, sorry, I was imprecise. I meant that in the example OP posted there is no forking involved. Gloss does not fork, it blocks on the main thread.

Comment: @Turion a process forking is different from using multiple threads. But if your claim is that gloss runs on the main thread, how do you square that with the error message above?

Comment: @DanRobertson well, that's basically what this question is about.

Answer (score 2):

Start ghci with -fno-ghci-sandbox. This is because OpenGL uses thread local state, which doesn't work when the running program is in a different thread.

```
stack ghci --ghc-options -fno-ghci-sandbox
```

This worked for me.

(Credit to danielkroeni on reddit for this solution.)